# Bad return type in lambda expression: Predicate<T> cannot be converted to Criteria<T>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following interfaces and class:

```
public interface Rule<T> {
   Predicate<T> evaluate();
}

public interface Criteria<T> {
   Predicate<T> evaluate();
}

public abstract class AbstractRule<T> implements Rule<T> {
   ...
   Set<Criteria<T>> criteria;
   ...

   @Override 
   @Nullable 
   public Predicate<T> evaluate() {
      return criteria.stream().reduce((c1, c2) -> c1.evaluate().and(c2.evaluvate()))
             .orElse(null);
   }
}
```

The AbstractRule class contains a set of Criteria. I want to do the evaluation on the Rule by evaluating each of the Criteria. I got compilation error on the c1.evaluate().and(c2.evaluate()) as mentioned in the title.

How should I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your interfaces are very confusing.  It doesn't look like they should _extend_ `Predicate`, just have a `Predicate<T>` return type on their method.  Or, rather, you should pick one -- _either_ extend `Predicate<T>` _or_ have a method returning a `Predicate<T>`.  Not both.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for your suggestion. I removed the `extends Predicate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this? you should transform a `Criteria` to a `Predicate` first.

```
abstract class AbstractRule<T> implements Rule<T> {
    Set<Criteria<T>> criteria;

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Predicate<T> evaluate() {
        return criteria.stream().map(Criteria::evaluate)
                                .reduce(Predicate::and)
                                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```